# Configure diagnostic aggregator to ignore a diagnostic?

Tags: ros, diagnostics, diagnostic-aggregator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to configure the diagnostic aggregator to ignore a particular diagnostic message? In my case, the xsens_driver always publishes GPS warnings since there is no GPS attached.

I understand that this could be addressed at the driver layer, but it seems like something useful to have at the aggregator level.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41591/configure-diagnostic-aggregator-to-ignore-a-diagnostic?/) by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3838 on 2012-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The docs say, there is a DiscardAnalyzer. I've never used it though.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/diagnostic_aggregator

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the device is known to be missing, you can delete that stanza from the [aggregator configuration](http://ros.org/wiki/diagnostics/Tutorials/Configuring%20Diagnostic%20Aggregators).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-08-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1